# cygwin bash getting last modified userid of a specific file

Tags: bash, cygwin

I am trying to get the username of the person who modified a specific file:

```
stat -c "%u" somefilename.name
```

this script returns a number like `544`

what does that mean? i was hoping to get the username like `myUsername`?

Answer (score 1):

You get the numerical userid from this commmand (edit: the userid of the owner, not the user who last modified the file). To get the related username, try `getent passwd 544` (I have no idea if that works like this on Cygwin).

You can try to combine these commands:

```
getent passwd $(stat -c "%u" somefilename.name)
```

Comment: thanks! i did man getent, but it doesnt have this. would there be a way to do this on one line instead of having to do the stat etc and then getent? i need to do a count of how many files every user modified

Comment: @АртёмЦарионов I just edited the combination command before receiving your comment :)

Comment: -bash: getent: command not found

Comment: @АртёмЦарионов: You don't get the information you want this way anyway, as I just realized. It shows the owner of a file, not who last modifed it.

Comment: oh i see! owner = person who created?

Comment: Usually, owner = person who created, but this doesn't change if someone else modifies it. The OS doesn' t keep track of this info.

Comment: whats the diff between owner and modifier\

Comment: modifier doesn't exist as an information in the file system.

Comment: no kidding! thats interesting. but this is windows!

Comment: Doesn't matter. NTFS doesn't track this either.

Comment: but in windows i am able to right click on a file and get the properties, the properties will say who edited it last

Comment: @АртёмЦарионов: No, not in the general case. It might work with some specific file formats  the explorer knows or has a plugin for (like MS-Office), but then it will get it out of the metainformations of the file, not from the file system. Test it with a plaintext notepad file.

Comment: getent isnt working on cygwin!

Answer (score 0):

It is the ID of the user. Issue:

```
awk -F: '{if ($3 == "544") print $1;}' /etc/passwd
```

to see the account name.

Now, you'll see `Administrators`, which probably isn't very helpful for you, but that's how Cygwin sees the owner.

See http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/ntsec.html and especially chapter `Example 3.3. /etc/passwd` there for more information.

Comment: This is cygwin, on Windows.

Comment: interesting! here's what i did $ grep $(stat -c "%u" woodland\ terrace.lnk) /etc/passwd
SYSTEM:*:18:544:,S-1-5-18::
LocalService:*:19:544:U-NT AUTHORITY\LocalService,S-1-5-19::
NetworkService:*:20:544:U-NT AUTHORITY\NetworkService,S-1-5-20::
Administrators:*:544:544:,S-1-5-32-544::

Comment: which one would be the username here?

Comment: Edited my answer.